# Widget Stop on Android KitKat After Removing It From Recent App

Tags: android, widget, android-4.4-kitkat

Is this a new behavior of Android KitKat or any technical explanation for this?

Reproduce Step by Step

1. Put any clock widget on Home Screen
2. Enter the widget Setting
3. Remove the widget Setting from Recent App

Prior KitKat, removing the widget setting from Recent Apps will not kill the widget service. Now, the clock will die.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here.
After searching web for a while, I found this issue. It might be a bug.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes I think it is the same issue we are all have.